# Can't run type(x) on a list of strings in Python

Tags: python-2.7, list, nonetype

It seems like my list of strings is a None object, even though I'm sure there is data.

I have a list of strings

```
d=["'Jan 2018'","'Feb 2018'","'Mar 2018'","'Jun 2018'"]
type(d)
```

This gives me a

```
'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I'm not sure what's going on. I can run `print` statements and get data, I can loop through the list and print out elements as well, but I can't get `type`.

Comment: Have you defined `type` as a variable, e.g. `type = None` previously in your code?

Comment: I did, thanks for pointing it out. I assumed python wouldn't let me do it so didn't think about checking that.

Answer (score 1):

I had previously defined a variable named Type:

`Type=1`

Comment: Hm - still not clear to me - can someone familiar with how this is an answer add some more context?

Comment: The problem is that the OP had declared a variable named `Type`. The (implied) solution is to remove or rename it.